# Here's The CA Animation Sequencing Sitch

Tags: ios, core-animation

I asked a question ([Animation Sometimes Doesn't Occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056619/animation-sometimes-doesnt-occur)) a while ago about an animation not, apparently, happening sometimes. I got no helpful answers. So, after much research and playing around, I discovered that sometimes the animation that is supposed to happen second, sometimes happens first. The other one does happen, just not when it is expected to happen. The two animations are "flip" and "disappear." As an example, there are four tiles. When one tile is touched, it flips. When a second tile is touched it is supposed to flip. If the tiles match, both tiles are disappeared. If they are not matched, the tiles flip back. The flipback animation has always occurred correctly, so far as I have been able to tell. In other words - the first tile is flipped. The second tile is flipped. The tiles do not match. The two tiles flipback. As for when the tiles match, the first tile flips correctly. Sometimes the second tile flips correctly and then they both disappear (animation group of rotate and shrink). Sometimes the second tile does not flip correctly, but they both disappear before the second tile does its flip. This is not acceptable.

This is what I have tried so far - I have tried NSThread pausing. That didn't work because the whole thread was paused, which didn't let the animation that hadn't occurred occur. I looked into NSTimer - but the method that is being called has two parameters which means I have to do NSInvocation and I haven't figured that out yet - and not sure it would work. Right now, I have put in a flag that marks when flip animations are completed. If this method eventually works, I have to figure out how to account for flipping individual tiles over and back again without upping the completion count. Anyway - using this method, I need to figure out how to tell my second animation to wait until the first animation is completed before running.

What I would ideally like to be able to do is to tell the disappear animation to always wait until the second tile is completely flipped before committing.

What I can't figure out is a) why sometimes the animations happen in the correct order, sometimes they don't and b) when the animations are trying to not happen in the correct order, how to force them to occur in the correct order.

Not really sure what code would be helpful for you to see. Ask and I shall provide!

Here is the code that calls the animations:

```
-(void)buttonPressed: (UIButton*)buttoni 
{
    [self flipTiles:(UIButton *)buttoni];
    [self twoTilesFlipped];
}
```

Clearly, the flipTiles animation is called first. What I don't understand is why it sometimes isn't called until after the code that is called in twoTilesFlipped. I thought that programming was about logic and this just doesn't make logical sense to me. Oh, I just had a thought...I am going to put in a NSTimer delay in this code - maybe that will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

That seems to have done the trick. There are some tweaks that I obviously need to fix now, but at least it works everytime.

This is what I added:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(twoTilesFlipped)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
```

so the final code for the method was:

```
-(void)buttonPressed: (UIButton*)buttoni 
{
    [self flipTiles:(UIButton *)buttoni];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(twoTilesFlipped)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}
```